# Added property to struct which in Swift - invalidates existing objects

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, option-type

I am new to Swift, but have some basic experience with Objective-C programming, and Swift seems much simpler.

However, I can't quite understand the `struct` thing. I followed a tutorial on how to use Firebase Realtime Database, and this tutorial were using a model to store the data.

But when I modified the `struct` with additional properties, the previously saved entries in the database is not showing up. I think it's because the model doesn't recognize the object in the database because it has different properties, but how can I make a property optional? So that old entries in the database with different structure (missing properties) are still valid and showing up?

Here is the model. The new property added is all the references to the `description`.

```swift
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct InsuranceItem {

    let ref: DatabaseReference?
    let key: String
    let name: String
    let timestamp: Int
    let itemValue: Int
    let description: String?
    let userId: String?

    init(name: String, timestamp: Int, itemValue: Int = 0, description: String = "", userId: String, key: String = "") {
        self.ref = nil
        self.key = key
        self.name = name
        self.timestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
        self.itemValue = itemValue
        self.description = description
        self.userId = userId
    }

    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard
            let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject],
            let name = value["name"] as? String,
            let timestamp = value["timestamp"] as? Int,
            let itemValue = value["itemValue"] as? Int,
            let description = value["description"] as? String,
            let userId = value["userId"] as? String else { return nil }

        self.ref = snapshot.ref
        self.key = snapshot.key
        self.name = name
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.itemValue = itemValue
        self.description = description
        self.userId = userId
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> Any {
        return [
            "name": name,
            "timestamp": timestamp,
            "itemValue": itemValue,
            "description": description!,
            "userId": userId!
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `guard` clause in your init or rather why is the optional attributes included in the `guard` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic bit is your failable init, `init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot)`. You fail the init even if an `Optional` property is missing, which is incorrect. You should only include the non-Optional properties in your `guard` statement, all others should simply be assigned with the optional casted value.

```
init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    guard
        let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any],
        let name = value["name"] as? String,
        let timestamp = value["timestamp"] as? Int,
        let itemValue = value["itemValue"] as? Int else { return nil }

    self.ref = snapshot.ref
    self.key = snapshot.key
    self.name = name
    self.timestamp = timestamp
    self.itemValue = itemValue

    // Optional properties
    let description = value["description"] as? String
    let userId = value["userId"] as? String
    self.description = description
    self.userId = userId
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but your `toAnyObject` function is unsafe, since you are force-unwrapping `Optional` values. Simply keep them as `Optional`s without any unwrapping and add `as Any` to silence the warning for implicit coersion.

```
func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    return [
        "name": name,
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "itemValue": itemValue,
        "description": description as Any,
        "userId": userId as Any
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I thought the initiation failed somewhere, but didn't know why. Thanks you for your feedback, I should really read more about structures and optionals.